# How can I create a table for my database in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am simply trying to create a table so I can insert rows, etc. in the database but I can't seem to get it to work. I have connected to the database but can't create tables. I just can't find a clear solution online for how to create a table in MySQLi, not MySQL... plus I'm a beginner.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("server.server","usernamedb","password","usernamedb");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
} else {
printf("Connected.\n");

}

$mysqli->query("create table items(cid integer, itemname(256)");

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please put the actual query you used instead of `"This is where I would create the table"`.

Comment: Okay, I updated it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming it's a syntax error with your `itemname` column since you don't correctly specify the type. You probably want `itemname varchar(256)`. You should also enable some sort of mysql error reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a create table statement?

Syntax example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size),
column_name2 data_type(size),
column_name3 data_type(size),
....
);
```

Real example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

You're line would look like:

```
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE Persons (PersonID int, LastName varchar(255), FirstName varchar(255), Address varchar(255), City varchar(255));");
```

Comment: Okay, where do I insert that, do I need the query statement before. So $mysqli->query(CREATE TABLE Persons....); ??

Comment: Right where you have it is fine. After you create it you'll be able to use it.

Comment: Nevermind, got it! Thank you! Can I do something similar to insert rows?

Comment: Yep. Instead of create it should be insert into tblname...